# Intermittent TestCafe Hang Issue

Tags: testcafe

I'm on an opensource project that's using TestCafe for our e2e UI tests.
https://github.com/cloud-carbon-footprint/cloud-carbon-footprint/

We're having some odd behavior where perhaps 1/2 the time when we run the tests locally, they hang right after starting. This is for a local run with `yarn headed` or `yarn headless` in the packages/integration-tests folder of the linked repo.

The browsers open, the tests begin, it prints the header, and then it just stops, always at the same early point, never providing any results. In headed mode the page appears to be stuck on the TestCafe loading widget (see screenshot), never loading the actual page under test.

If I wait long enough without cancelling, I get this error:
"ERROR The Chrome 102.0.5005.61 / macOS 10.15.7 browser disconnected. If you did not close the browser yourself, browser performance or network issues may be at fault"

To be clear, the issue itself is inconsistent, but when it happens it's always the same behavior and the exact same point in the test.

Also notably, it's not random every run so much as some kind of error state. Sometimes closing and re-opening my IDE will cause the tests to run correctly, but once they're hanging, they tend to keep hanging.

I'm a little baffled, so I'm hoping someone has some idea what's going on or has seen something similar.

Comment: To help you with this issue, I need to reproduce the problematic behavior. I assumed I should run 'yarn start' and 'yarn headless' or 'headed' tasks in the repository's 'integration-tests' package, but 'start-api' threw the following error on my machine:

Compilation error in ~/cloud-carbon-footprint/packages/api/src/server.ts

Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.

Comment: Please specify which steps I should perform to reproduce the issue with hanging tests on my side.

Comment: You shouldn't have to run yarn start, just 'yarn install' in the root directory and then 'yarn head(ed/less)' in the integration-tests pacakage.

Comment: If I do not call 'yarn start' before running tests, they will hang because the '.before' hook [waits for](https://github.com/cloud-carbon-footprint/cloud-carbon-footprint/blob/trunk/packages/integration-tests/tests/app.test.js#L13) http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:4000/api/healthz to return 2xx infinitely, but nothing is deployed on my machine. Moreover, the tests' target page is http://localhost:3000/, so I assume I need to either deploy the app locally or change the URLs to a public instance of the web app.